# Prize distribution algorithm to handle ties

Tags: python, algorithm, math, statistics, game-engine

I'm trying to come up with a prize distribution algorithm that can scalably handle different number of players and factor in ties i.e in case the contestants fall in the same position.

This is what I have so far:

```
Distribution Formula        
P=((1-d)/1-d^n)*d^(p-1))*A      

Where:      
P   Prize   
n   Number of winners   
A   Total amout of money to share   
d   Distribution constant >0<1  
p   Position or rank of the user
```

Modeling it in Excel I get the following results:

```
Constants

A   50000
d   0.4
n   15
```

**Sample data**

**Distribution without ties**

```
Position (p)    Player  Prize (P)
1   A   30000.03221
2   B   12000.01288
3   C   4800.005154
4   D   1920.002062
5   E   768.0008246
6   F   307.2003299
7   C   122.8801319
8   D   49.15205278
9   E   19.66082111
10  F   7.864328444
11  C   3.145731378
12  D   1.258292551
13  E   0.5033170204
14  F   0.2013268082
15  C   0.08053072327
**Total     50000**
```

**Distribution with ties**

```
Position (p)    Player  Prize (P)
1   A   30000.03221
1   B   30000.03221
2   C   12000.01288
3   D   4800.005154
4   E   1920.002062
4   F   1920.002062
5   C   768.0008246
6   D   307.2003299
7   E   122.8801319
8   F   49.15205278
9   C   19.66082111
10  D   7.864328444
11  E   3.145731378
12  F   1.258292551
13  C   0.5033170204
**Total 81919.75242**
```

**Problem**

Not my second data with ties the total distributed prizes is more than 50000 which is what I wanted to share

**Desired results**

Users falling in the same position should get an equal amount and have the prizes well distributed to the other users. The total amount paid out should not be more than what was intended.

How can I improve the above function to achieve the above results.

Comment: Why not simply (30000+12000)/2 for A and B, and (768+307)/2 for E and F?

Comment: The problem with that is if we have so many ties on top if we simply divide chances are the guys after them might have more share than the leaders. I'm trying to think of a distribution that will scale well with different data sets

Comment: It's impossible for lower-placed players to get more than higher-placed tied players with the method I'm proposing. If the first 10 players are tied, and they all receive the average of the first ten prizes, then the tenth player's prize will increase; that will mean he still gets more than the eleventh-placed player.

Comment: @m69 You were right I was not testing it well. I made sure my value of n is of distinct positions and divided prize at the ties with the number of T(ties) at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let `MaxT` (default value 1) is maximum of all ties for various tied positions
2. Choose `d <= 1/MaxT`

   **UPDATE**: For example:

   > ```
   > 1   A   30000.03221 |
   > 1   B   30000.03221 |  Tie count T1 = 2
   > 2   C   12000.01288
   > 3   D   4800.005154
   > 4   E   1920.002062 | 
   > 4   F   1920.002062 |  Tie count T2 = 2
   > ```
   >
   > maxT = max of {T1, T2, .. Tn} = max {2, 2} = 2
3. Calculate prize money once for each unique position
4. For tied positions, just divide the prize money calculated in step #2 by no. of ties for the position (Tn) (Example: For position 1: 30000/2.0)

This scheme makes sure that total is A and prize value of a position is less than prize value of upper position, independent of ties.

Comment: Thanks @vcp for input. I still don't get the `MaxT` part. Kindly help clarify step 1 & 2 for me. What do you refer to MaxT in this case?

Comment: @felixcheruiyot I just added example to explain maxT

Comment: @vpc I took a lot of time to figure this one out but finally I got it. What I was missing is to make sure n is distinct with respect to position. Finally I got it and it works well.